# How to use MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter to convert Maps and List correctly?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson

In my Spring MVC project MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter configured as follows:

```
    <bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"></bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

For plain simple Java POJO Beans, serialization works well. All good. But, i also have Beans that include `Map`s that needed to be serialized as well, and it's fails (JsonMappingException).

From [Jackson instructions](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/), I know that to solve this what needed is to indicate the actual type for the object mapper. It looks like that:

```
Map<String, ResultValue> results = mapper.readValue(jsonSource,
                        new TypeReference<Map<String, ResultValue>>() { } );
```

How can be the same configuration be done to MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter (with based on Jackson2 object mapper)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your question what doesn't work, but I'm guessing that you have a bean that contains `java.util.Map` or `java.util.List` property and you're getting `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException` when deserializing that bean.

In that case you can give hints on fields with [`@JsonDeserialize`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Databind-Annotations#deserialization-reading-json) annotation. So for instance if you have a `java.util.Map<String, ResultValue>` field, you can annotate it like:

```
@JsonDeserialize(keyAs = String.class, contentAs = ResultValue.class)
public Map<String, ResultValue> map;
```

Comment: Thanks. Adding @JsonDeserialize as a "hint" helped.